# Event Scheduler não pode ser ativado

Tags: php, eventos, scheduler

Eu tenho um website e criei um sistema simples de expiração de anúncios através de um evento SQL, que corre de um determinado em um determinado tempo e altera o estado do anúncio se este o campo `dataexpiracao` tiver sido ultrapassado. Isto funciona bem no servidor local (XAMPP), no servidor de alojamento não me é permitido ativar o Event Scheduler.

Vale a pena contactar a empresa? Existe alguma forma de implementar um sistema do gênero sem ser através de eventos?

Comment: qual banco de dados você usa? Você não pode ativar o agendador de tarefas, ou não pode ativar um evento de banco de dados ?